# How to display a Button which hosts TextBlock with the style PhoneTextSubtleStyle?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, windows-phone-7.1

I need to create a button with two lines of text:

The first one is Command Title like "Save"

The second one is a Description of the Command like "The application state will be saved"

So I have written the next xaml:

```
<Button Margin="0,128,0,0" Padding="10,5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
  <StackPanel Margin="0" UseLayoutRounding="False">
    <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}">Save</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Margin="0">The application state will be saved</TextBlock>
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

This code working well except a one issue. The Description line becomes invisible when the button is pushed.

I'm sure the root cause is the low contrast color of the description line. But I don't know how to fix it.

Update: I have tried to use the PhoneTextSubtleStyle style but still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this

```
System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
or
System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
```

here is a link that will show an example of how to use this inside of a StackPanel

[How to: Change the Visibility Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748821%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could *retemplate* the `Button` (using the `Control.Template` property) to look different so that when pushed it no longer interferes with the content.

Comment: I have not worked with templates before, I'll investigate it. Thanks.